# Different builds based on targeting client vs server code

Tags: node.js, webpack

I currently have 2 separate webpack builds for server rendered vs client rendered code. Is there an easy way to change the build output based on server/client build?

For example something like this:

```js
// Have some code like this
if(is_client){
  console.log('x.y.z')
} else {
  server.log('x.y.z')
}

// Webpack outputs:
// replaced code in client.js
console.log('x.y.z')


// replaced code in server.js
server.log('x.y.z')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried anything like this?

```js
// webpack.config.js

module.exports = () => ['web', 'node'].map(target => {
  const config = { 
    target,
    context: path.resolve('__dirname', 'src'),
    entry: {
      [target]: ['./application.js'],
    },
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist', target),
      filename: '[name].js'
    },
    modules: { rules: ... },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        IS_NODE: JSON.stringify(target === 'node'),
        IS_WEB: JSON.stringify(target === 'web'),
      }),
    ],
  };

  return config;
});
```

```js
// later in your code

import logger from 'logger';

if (IS_NODE) {
  logger.log('this is node js');
}

if (IS_WEB) {
  console.log('this is web');
}
```

#### how the compilation works?

```js
// client.bundle.js
import logger from 'logger';

// DefinePlugin creates a constant expression which causes the code below to be unreachable
if (false) {
  logger.log('this is node js');
}

if (true) {
  console.log('this is web');
}
```

Finally you will produce your build in production mode, so webpack will include a plugin called `UglifyJS`, this has a feature called `dead code removal` (aka tree shaking), so it will delete any unused/unreachable code.

and the final result will look like:

```js
// node.bundle.js
import logger from 'logger';

console.log('this is node js');
```

```js
//web.bundle.js

console.log('this is node js');
```

Comment: I don't think that will do exactly what I want. I would ideally not want to include the server logging library in the final build for the client.

The solution I'm going with for now is to create a server specific entry point that imports the client entry point. Then it monkey patches console.log to point to the special logging function I want only on the server sided bundle.

This way my client code doesn't include the extra code!

Comment: this will do exactly that, have you tried it? (I've also updated with some info)

Comment: This is great thank you! I realize that this + tree shaking would have the desired outcome.